# /boot/efi can't be mounted after kernel update Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot, 13.04, updates, kernel, uefi

After installing the latest updates it appears that the new version of the kernel which was installed (3.8.0-29) will not boot properly.

Whenever I try to boot using this new kernel, I get an error message indicating that there was an error mounting `/boot/efi`.

This only happens with this new kernel, as starting up with the older kernel versions works fine.

In case this helps, I have a laptop with UEFI, and I dual boot Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 8.

Edit:
I tried everything in Rod Smith's answer but I am still having the issue

The exact error message is:

> An error occurred while mounting /boot/efi.
>
> Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

Pressing S just brings me to a terminal login screen, while pressing M brings me to a recovery terminal.

Here are the the results of the commands you asked me to run:

```
$ grep efi /etc/fstab
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=F433-DF4C  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1

$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="WINRE_DRV" UUID="4A46311E46310C67" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="F433-DF4C" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="LRS_ESP" UUID="5034-7FB2" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Windows8_OS" UUID="989E38469E381F66" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="LENOVO" UUID="32EE3B04EE3AC041" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda7: LABEL="PBR_DRV" UUID="14243C89243C703A" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="b5377bd7-1953-4cb0-b30d-9ee5a466760c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda9: UUID="be7e2af0-3cc7-4e3c-82a1-e28e3d4b4ba6" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="CRUZER" UUID="28A2-35DE" TYPE="vfat"
```

While `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` both look similar on my system `/dev/sda2` is the one with the "boot" flag, and changing the entry in fstab to the UUID for `/dev/sda3` made no difference.

Comment: Try `sudo dosfsck -a /dev/sda2` to automatically repair the ESP. If that doesn't help, post the output of the command.

Comment: @RodSmith It seems to be working now, but, due to some carelessness on my part, I'm not entirely sure what fixed it. I ran `sudo dosfsck -a /dev/sda2`, but I forgot to reboot afterwards, and I also decided to try reinstalling the kernel. One or both of those things worked, but I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my Ubuntu 13.04 system to kernel 3.8.0-29 and I had no problem with this. My suspicion is that you're experiencing filesystem damage. This is common on systems that dual-boot with Windows 8 because of a Windows 8 feature called "fast startup." This feature essentially turns the shutdown operation into a suspend-to-disk operation. This works fine on a single-boot computer, but when the computer dual-boots with another OS, the result is dangerous filesystem problems, at least on any filesystem that's shared between OSes (including the EFI System Partition [ESP]). To fix this, boot to Windows and [disable fast startup.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) Note that this feature is *not* the same as the fast boot option in your firmware; disabling this feature in the firmware does *not* disable it in Windows 8.

If you disable fast startup and the problem persists, then you could try doing a filesystem check on your ESP, as in `dosfsck /dev/sda1`. (The device file in Linux might be different, though. Use `parted` or GParted to find the FAT partition with a "boot flag" set, or use `gdisk` to find the partition with a type code of EF00.)

If the problem persists even after you disable fast boot and fix the filesystem, please try the following diagnostics:

```
grep efi /etc/fstab
sudo blkid
```

Compare the results -- the `/etc/fstab` file defines where partitions are mounted, and so searching it for `efi` should produce details on how your system is mounting the ESP. For instance, on my system, it shows the following:

```
$ grep efi /etc/fstab
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=FFB3-46B6  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

The `blkid` command produces information on all your computer's filesystems. You want to compare what it shows for your ESP (usually `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, or `/dev/sda3`) to what's in `/etc/fstab`. For instance:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="ESP" UUID="FFB3-46B6" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Fred" UUID="421258c1-e9b1-4b1b-9dd7-60b82e75f8c3" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="9108d33b-855d-49ba-8b9e-90f981a597ea" TYPE="swap"
```

In this case, `/dev/sda1` is the ESP -- it's a FAT (`TYPE="vfat"`) filesystem, and its serial number matches what's in `/etc/fstab` (`UUID="FFB3-46B6"`), so all is in order. A mismatch of the serial numbers or some other detail might cause the problem you're encountering. If you need more help, please edit your post with this information and the *exact* error message you're seeing.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but I'm still having the problem.  See the updated info in my question.

Answer (score -1):

I've just had a similar problem when using boot-repair to move to UEFI. Sounds silly, but I just put double quotes around the UUID value, did `sudo mount -a` (or reboot)  and the error went away.
So I would change your /etc/fstab entry from

```
UUID=F433-DF4C  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
```

to

```
UUID="F433-DF4C"  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
```

Comment: Well, the manpage of `fstab` shows it should be without quotes. And all my systems run perfectly fine on configurations without the quotes. Does not make sense to me why this would make a difference at all.